# How to use Lucene on my server

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, solr, lucene

I want to use Apache Solr, or Elastic Search, or some form of Apache Lucene on my website. Do I have to have a completely separate server for it to run on?

My website runs on AWS on a Tomcat instance. I know that I can simply spin up an elastic search instance on AWS and use that. My goal is to do it without having to spend that money, and just use it on the server I already have. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is usually what problem you want to solve, and then deciding whether Elastic or Solr can be the solution to that problem.

But yes, you can run both [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html) and [Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr) on your existing server. You'd install either by following the installation guides in their manuals, and they'll both run as server daemons separate from your existing Tomcat installation.

Older versions of Solr was distributed as a .war file that you could run in Tomcat, but this is not (officially) supported any longer, and is not recommended (at it would require a bit of manual hacking).

You'd then write code in your existing webapp to query Solr or Elasticsearch for the information you want to retrieve.

Comment: Ok, if I'm running my site on AWS, do you know how I would install it on that server? I can do it locally, that's not the problem. Doing it while on AWS is the issue.

Comment: That depends on what part of AWS you're using, but for regular EC2 you'd download the archives, unpack them and then for Solr, launch Solr with `bin/solr`. The installation guides should show you how to do each step.

Comment: I've installed to AWS EC2 (which is a Red Hat variant) and just used the "install for production" instructions on the Solr wiki.  My IT guy wanted some changes to where/how the init script ran and he made those changes, but it worked fine straight out of the box.

Comment: And, since we didn't call it out - Solr runs on it's own embedded jetty server (at least the latest versions do).  If you want SolrCloud you need zookeeper too, but if you're just looking at a standalone Solr install, you won't need to worry about that...

Comment: @jb62 Solr also bundles zookeeper, but yes, its recommended to create your own zookeeper ensemble and not use the embedded ZK.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments, guys.